# How to append all selected values from all pages into a text box when we are using pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an index.html page which has an option to select multiple client_ip's and I'm using pagination to display multiple client_ip's.

Please refer index.html in this url: http://plnkr.co/edit/y7qAUOwVfvKqQBjYW3JF?p=preview

Suppose in this url in 1st page,if I select 2 clent_ip's,those two client_ip's are displayed in the client_ip text box.Then,moving to 2nd page if I select one  client_ip over there,I'm able to see only one client_ip but not 3 client_ip's in the client_ip text box.

But now I'm trying to display all the selected client_ip's of all pages into a client_ip text box.

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8" ></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <form action="/some" method="get">
      Client Ip :
      <input type="text" id="ip" name="client_ip" style="width: 600px;" />
      <div id="subDiv">
        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <br/>

  <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  </table>

  <script>


    $(document).ready(function() {
      var tabulate = function(data, columns) {
        var svg = d3.select('#ip').append("svg")
        var table = d3.select('#example')
        var thead = table.append('thead')
        var tbody = table.append('tbody')

        thead.append('tr')
          .selectAll('th')
          .data(columns)
          .enter()
          .append('th')
          .text(function(d) {
            return d
          })

        var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append('tr')

        var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
          .data(function(row) {
            return columns.map(function(column) {
              return {
                column: column,
                value: row[column]
              }
            })
          })
          .enter()
          .append('td')
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.value
          })
          .append("input")
          .attr("id", "change")
          .attr("type", "checkbox")
          .style("float", "left")
          .on("click", function(d,i) { 

        var csv = $(':checkbox[id=change]:checked').map(function(){return $(this).parent().text();}).get().join(',');

        $('#ip').val(csv);

});


        return table;
      }

      d3.csv('http://localhost:3000/getcsv', function(data) {
        var columns = ['client_ip']
        tabulate(data, columns)

        $('#example').DataTable({
          "pagingType": "full_numbers"
        });
      });

      $("#ip").val('');

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

Comment: Getting help is supposed to start with you trying to do it, and showing where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another approach is push selected Ips into an array and splice it if unchecked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <form action="/some" method="get">
      Client Ip :
      <input type="text" id="ip" name="client_ip" style="width: 600px;" />
      <div id="subDiv">
        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <br/>

  <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  </table>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var selectedIps = [];
      var tabulate = function(data, columns) {
        var svg = d3.select('#ip').append("svg")
        var table = d3.select('#example')
        var thead = table.append('thead')
        var tbody = table.append('tbody')

        thead.append('tr')
          .selectAll('th')
          .data(columns)
          .enter()
          .append('th')
          .text(function(d) {
            return d
          })

        var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append('tr')

        var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
          .data(function(row) {
            return columns.map(function(column) {
              return {
                column: column,
                value: row[column]
              }
            })
          })
          .enter()
          .append('td')
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.value
          })
          .append("input")
          .attr("id", "change")
          .attr("type", "checkbox")
          .style("float", "left")
          .on("change", function(d, i) {
            if ($(this)[0].checked) {
              if (selectedIps.indexOf(d.value) < 0) {
                selectedIps.push(d.value);
              }
            } else {
              if (selectedIps.indexOf(d.value) > -1) {
                selectedIps.splice(selectedIps.indexOf(d.value), 1);
              }
            }
            $('#ip').val(selectedIps.join(','));
          });


        return table;
      }

      d3.csv('getcsv', function(data) {
        var columns = ['client_ip']
        tabulate(data, columns)

        $('#example').DataTable({
          "pagingType": "full_numbers"
        });
      });

      $("#ip").val('');

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AAiX3V5nL6q44BHkKrsj?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot .This worked for me.Can u explain  this code once.It will be helpful to me                                                                                        .on("change", function(d, i) {
            if ($(this)[0].checked) {
              if (selectedIps.indexOf(d.value) < 0) {
                selectedIps.push(d.value);
              }
            } else {
              if (selectedIps.indexOf(d.value) > -1) {
                selectedIps.splice(selectedIps.indexOf(d.value), 1);
              }
            }
            $('#ip').val(selectedIps.join(','));
          });

Comment: whenever a change event occurs on checkbox, above function checks whether checkbox is seleted or not.. If it is selected, its value is pushed into array `selectedIps` and if its unchecked, its value is removed from the  `seletedIps` array. and at the last, the value is printed into input box.

Comment: I didn't get about  selectedIps.indexOf(d.value) < 0 & selectedIps.indexOf(d.value) > -1.Why we are comparing with <0 & >-1

Comment: It simply checks for the index of selected checkbox's value. If its already exists in the array it will skip it else it will push it. `indexOf` function returns `-1` if value does not exists and `>-1` if value exists.

Answer (score 0):

Just change :

```
$('#ip').val(csv)
```

To :

```
$('#ip').val($('#ip').val() + ' ' + csv);
```

it will save the previous value and will also set the current new values